# Why code is being executed in such strange sequence in c?

Tags: c, fgets

```
int is_valid(char *input)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0;; i++)
    {
        // Check for null terminator
        if ( ! input[i])
        {
            printf("stop executing is_valid()");
            return 0;
        }

        // Will be executed for null terminator... o_O
        printf("%c isdigit: %d\n", input[i], isdigit(input[i]));
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char input[80];
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    is_valid(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 isdigit: 1
0 isdigit: 1
1 isdigit: 1

 isdigit: 0 // Why is that here? null terminator after return?!
stop executing is_valid()invalid input!
```

Why null terminator is processed via `isdigit` before return? And.. ok, why if condition is executed after it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why null terminator is processed via `isdigit` before return?

It is not. It is executed for `'\n'` character read by `fgets`.

C11-§7.21.7.2

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the `stream` pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`. **No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array**.

For the input

```
101
```

there are `5` characters in there

```
101\n\0
```

`\n` is not a digit of course.

You need to add a condition for `\n` too

```
if (input[i] == '\0' || input[i] == '\n')
{
    printf("stop executing is_valid()");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, you mean my input string has two symbols at the end? `'\n'` and `'\0'`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `scanf("%d",&char[i]`)  to get the input. Since `fgets` also accepts newline operator, that is the extra output you are getting, the checking for `"\n"` taken by `fgets`.

Comment: `scanf` is inappropriate, because i have to perform deep validation for input.